# How was DC restored in windows 2008 before windows 2012 VM generation ID?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, virtual-machines

Windows server 2012 got this new thing called "VM generation ID" which protects DC restoration from snapshots so it doesn't impair the system (getting new invocation ID and requesting new RID pool etc.). What would happen if I did a restore of DC from a snapshot in Hyper-V 2008? I need this kind of information for my Windows server 2008. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You back it up like you would a physical server, and conversely, restore using actual system state backups and not snapshots and VHD copies.

## Invocation ID

When you perform a System State restore on a Domain Controller, the invocation ID automatically changes - letting other Domain Controllers know that this is technically a "new" database replica.

If, on the other hand, you revert to an older snapshot on a VM that doesn't support VM generation ID, you should expect to see a [**USN rollback**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2cae85b-41ac-497f-8cd1-5fbaa6740ffe(v=ws.10)#usn_and_usn_rollback) - that is, other Domain Controllers won't replicate the changes originating from your reverted DC, since the **U**pdate **S**equence **N**umbers on that domain controller falls below the [High Water-Mark](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961798.aspx#EKAA) value that the other DC's currently know of.

## RID Pool

Once again, during a System State restore, the RID Pool allocated to the DC is automatically invalidated.

If the DC you restored also holds the RID Master FSMO and you did not transfer or seize the role to another DC prior to the restore, you can bump the next RID Pool allocation up by a 100000 as [described in this procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781218(v=ws.10).aspx#RaiseRIDPool)

Comment: Lets say you did a revert to an older snapshot on windows server 2008 and the domain controller replication is messed up because of that. What would be the course of actions to restore it back to full functioning and also full replication? If it's possible of course. Thanks for your answer it's really helpful.

Comment: Demote and re-promote it - that way it's "new", get's a new account, Invocation ID and RID Pool